# Expect Function Behaving Strangely

Tags: expect

Working on a script using `Expect` and it's giving me odd output.  Here's my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
cd ~/Downloads/
spawn /usr/sbin/program
expect "Enter Username: "
send "username\r"
expect "Enter Password: "
send "password\r"
```

My standard output from that looks like this:

> Enter Username: username
>
> username
>
> Enter Password: home@debian:/home/debian#

It just exits my program.  Normally if I have entered an incorrect password, it prompts me again.  I'm also confused about why it printed "username" twice.

Comment: Before using expect I suggest to try this: `echo -e "username\npassword" | /usr/sbin/program`

Comment: Take a look: [Expect FAQ: Why does it send back the same string twice?](http://expect.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#q52)

Comment: That did not work, it froze my terminal

Comment: That only looks like it deals with the case where he spawns cat first, which I'm not doing

Comment: What is the program supposed to do? Is this a standard program? It's hard to advise you what you should do without knowing what you want to do after sending the password. As it stands, the script finishes and then exits.

Comment: If you want to stay in the program after sending the password, use the `interact` command. Otherwise the Expect script exits.

Answer (score 0):

If the program is meant to run to completion after entering the password, just add this at the end:

```
expect eof
```

That should wait until the spawned process finishes and closes.